# Chevereto installation with mod_rewrite enabled

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I try to install `Chevereto` free edition on `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS` with `Apache 2.4.7`. I get auto redirect to folder `/install` during installation process, which doesn't exists. `/app/install/installer.php` gives error message:

> This file cannot be directly accessed.

Apache `mod_rewrite` is enabled. `/install` should be handled by `index.php` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override has to be allowed in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file.

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```